# How to upgrade the Qt version through the command line?

Tags: qt, ubuntu-18.04

I currently have QT version 5.9 on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 but I need at least QT version 5.10 in order to have certain functionality. Is there a way to upgrade through command line or should I just re-download from the website? If I do re-download from the website will I still have the 5.9 version?

Answer (score 3):

To install QT 5.14 on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS x86_64:

- `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:beineri/opt-qt-5.14.0-bionic`
- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install qt514-meta-minimal -y`
- `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/qt514/lib/`

By using the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable, you will tell the system to use the version provided by the path (so 5.14 in this case) without having to remove the default installed version.

More details: [https://launchpad.net/~beineri/+archive/ubuntu/opt-qt-5.14.0-bionic](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebeineri/+archive/ubuntu/opt-qt-5.14.0-bionic)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO! The easiest way is to upgrade your Ubuntu version (especially as there is already a newer LTE release). If you can't do that, then you can look into PPA-s which ships newer Qt version for older Ubuntu versions (for example: [https://launchpad.net/~beineri/+archive/ubuntu/opt-qt-5.12.0-bionic](https://launchpad.net/%7Ebeineri/+archive/ubuntu/opt-qt-5.12.0-bionic)), but be warned that this makes the distributions of your project more cumbersome (as on the target system your application will depend on packages which are not in the main repositories.